# Draw a 8x8 squares using canvas and bitmap in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am fairly new with android development. I am trying to take a 8x8 array of integers and make a 8x8 square (64 squares) using canvas and bitmap, a picture below shows what I want to accomplish. Each square would correspond to the index of the integer array, and the color of the square will change depending on the integers(0-255).

Currently, I am just trying to draw the layout of my application, but I am stuck on drawing the array of squares using canvas and bitmap. I have looked at different sources and the following two seems like very close to what I want to do.

[source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361231/android-draw-bitmap-within-canvas): I declared a 2d bitmap variable like this: `Bitmap bmp[][] = new Bitmap[8][8]` and tried to use a double for loop, but my app crashes because of

> Boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled() on a null reference

[source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274170/how-to-convert-2d-int-array-to-bitmap-in-android) I tried alexander zak's answer but I am not sure how to draw squares on to the screen using the Bitmap return value.

Any one have any suggestions on how I can accomplish my goal? thanks for all your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by:

Create a bitmap object`Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(8, 8, bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`

set each pixels(64) `bmp.setPixel(index_of_the_bitmap_x, index_of_the_bitmap_y, int color)`using a double for loop or which ever.

Draw a bitmap onto the canvas and scale it to the size of a rectangle: `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, destinationRet, null);`